# Conversion file from utf16 to utf8 doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, utf-8, utf-16

I want to implement program, which converts utf16 file to utf8 and utf8 file to utf16. Here is my code:
I open file:

```
 ifstream sourceFile(sourceFilePath, std::ifstream::binary);

ofstream outFile("/home/myuser/Desktop/res_file.txt");
This code converts utf8 to utf16 and IT WORKS:
vector<unsigned short> utf16line;
        utf8::utf8to16(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFile),
                       std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
                       back_inserter(utf16line));


        outFile.write((char*)&utf16line[0], utf16line.size()*2);
```

BUT THE NEXT CODE DOESN'T WORK:

```
 vector<unsigned char> utf8result;
        utf8::utf16to8(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFile),
                       std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
                       back_inserter(utf8result));
        outFile.write((char*)&utf8result[0], utf8result.size());
```

Instead of getting correct file this:

```
some string
12345
nnnnn
```

I have this:

```
뿯뺿some string  //chines symbols shouldn't be there
12345
nnnnn
```

What is wrong with conversation from utf-16 file to utf-8 file ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does converted text from utf-8 to utf-16 is not written properly into file ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475494/why-does-converted-text-from-utf-8-to-utf-16-is-not-written-properly-into-file)

Comment: I deleted previous wrong question. This is the other question.

Comment: Instead of deleting the former question, you should have edited it to improve it.

Comment: Does your input file have a Byte Order Mark (BOM) 1st 4 bytes?  Most editors won't show them look at the input file in a hex editor. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: yes, it is probably BOM, but what should I do to avoid this BOM ? how to fix it  ?

Comment: What is `utf8::utf16to8` supposed to be? A custom implementation? A 3rd party implementation? Certainly not a standard implementation. Does it have any optional settings? For instance, `std::wstring_convert` using `std::codecvt_utf8_utf16` has options to discard and generate a BOM during UTF8<->UTF16 conversions.